# Can an HTTP proxy handle inbound CONNECT requestd over HTTP/2?

Tags: http, http2, http-proxy

AFAIK, HTTP proxy CONNECT HTTP/1.1 requests tunnel a single TCP connection. After any TCP connection is closed, both upstream and downstream connections are closed. Connection reuse isn't possible. Is it possible to make HTTP/2 requests to a proxy to mux multiple tunneled over a single TCP (upstream) connection to avoid the cost of TCP handshake? Does the HTTP/2 standard allow the CONNECT method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in HTTP/2 the [CONNECT method exists](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#CONNECT) too:

"In HTTP/2, the CONNECT method is used to establish a tunnel over a single HTTP/2 stream to a remote host for similar purposes"